# Which version of Zend should I use for a symfony 1.4 project?

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, symfony-1.4

I have a legacy symfony 1.4 project in which I want to integrate Lucene as it is described in [jobeet](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/17?orm=Doctrine) tutorial.

Since things move forward, I wonder which version of Zend Framework with Lucene is recommended for symfony1.4?

Can I use ZF2 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea if you can use ZF2 inside a symfony 1 project (but it should only be a mater of loading classes correctly and have the proper PHP version), but I can tell you that [my website](http://www.j0k3r.net/search?query=zend) is running on symfony 1.4 and I have ZF 1.10 on it to use Lucene.

Taking a look at the svn, I can see the external source is on http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/ which is the 1.10 ZF branch.

If I remember well, I used the same approach described in the Jobeet tutorial to use Lucene.

Comment: i didnt had the nerves to try ZF2, instead i stayed with the latest ZF 1 release (1.12.2) from here: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives , seems to work